# Can i display my name in messages send through whatsapp api?

Tags: javascript, php, whatsapp

As the title says, Can i display my name in messages send through whatsapp API?

I am using whatsapp PHP API https://github.com/WHAnonymous/Chat-API/ to send messages. But i need to send the message without displaying my name instead displaying the name.